# Mysql - comparing two strings in the same table on different dates

Tags: mysql

Relevant table structure is:

```
id(INT), reference_id(INT), status(VARCHAR(20)), date(TIMESTAMP)
```

This record is updated once per day.

Problem:
I want to display each record where the status field, which is static most of the time, is different to the one on the preceeding day, thus being able to show the date a status changed and display a history.

How?

Pseudo:

```
Show * where status for today != status for yesterday
```

Early logic, but my limited knowledge of mysql is causing me to hit a wall.

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()
UNION
SELECT table_name.status AS yesterday_status WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE() - 1
```

I was then going to compare them both in perl, which is not so efficient so I'm hoping somebody can share some enlightenment...

Comment: Extra info: For both records, reference_id needs to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach. It is not exactly what you were asking for, but if maybe you will like my solution.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/896b4/7

```
SELECT 
   today.*,
   yesterday.*
FROM t_status today
LEFT JOIN t_status yesterday
ON DATE(yesterday.date)<DATE(today.date)
   AND yesterday.reference_id  = today.reference_id
   AND yesterday.status != today.status
WHERE  DATE(today.date) = CURDATE()
ORDER BY yesterday.date DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

**UPDATE** Or probably I misunderstood your goal, and you need only compare **yesterdays** status, not all past statuses. If so you can try this `INNER JOIN`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd61f1/4

```
SELECT 
   today.*,
   yesterday.*
FROM t_status today
INNER JOIN t_status yesterday
ON DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY) = DATE(yesterday.date)
   AND yesterday.reference_id  = today.reference_id
   AND yesterday.status != today.status
WHERE  DATE(today.date) = CURDATE();
```

You are welcome if any questions.

Comment: That's the one!

Thanks for this - I understand a bit more about joins now as a result. Although I'll need to tweak further to get it just-so, this has helped me over that wall. Well done. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below query shows the records along with the previous day's record (I assumed that reference_id is also a join citeria, if not, just remove it)

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table t1
left join table t2 on t1.reference_id=t2.reference_id and date(t1.date)-1=date(t2.date)
```

You can even filter it further to display only those pairs, where the previous day's status is different (note that the join changes from left to inner, since if there is no previous day's record, that's not a change is status):

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.reference_id=t2.reference_id and date(t1.date)-1=date(t2.date) and t1.status<>t2.status
```

Answer (score 0):

I think query should be like 
select * from tablename where status <> (select * from tablename where date=Sysdate-1)
Sysdate is use for System date.